# How to build a SWC with documentation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, ant, swc, asdoc

**UPDATE**

1. <s>solved: embed doc with swc</s>
2. <s>solved: weird param names: param0, param1, etc.</s>

---

I created a `swc` lib using `compc`.

Then I created the lib doc with `asdoc`.

But I dont know how to bind them together, since when I use the .swc in another project params names are weird (like `myMethod(param0:Number)`) and there is no doc description.

I'm using Ant, this is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="uil" default="compile" basedir=".">

    <property name="flexsdk" location="C:/sdks/flex_sdk_4.6/bin"/>

    <property name="compc" location="${flexsdk}/compc.exe"/>
    <property name="asdoc" location="${flexsdk}/asdoc.exe"/>

    <property name="src" location="../src"/>
    <property name="bin" location="../bin"/>

    <target name="compile" depends="doc">
        <exec executable="${compc}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-debug=false" />
            <arg line="-optimize=true" />
            <arg line="-strict=true" />
            <arg line="-locale=en_US" />
            <arg line="-include-sources=${src}" />
            <arg line="-output=${bin}/uil.swc" />
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="doc">
        <exec executable="${asdoc}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="-main-title 'UIL API Documentation'" />
            <arg line="-window-title 'UIL API Documentation'" />
            <arg line="-source-path ${src} -doc-sources ${src}" />
            <arg line="-output ${bin}/uil-asdoc" />
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

**Edit: How it was solved**

The line that make all the magic is this:

```
<taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar" />
```

Then I replaced all my `<exec>` tags to `<compc>` and `<asdoc>` and everything worked. You can see the entire code [here.](https://github.com/ofabricio/uil/blob/master/as3/ant/build.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `zip` ant target as in the [`build.xml`](https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/build/ant/build.xml) of the `Starling` framework:

```
<!-- call asdoc to generate dita xml files -->
<asdoc output="${temp.dir}" lenient="true" failonerror="true" keep-xml="true" skip-xsl="true" fork="true">
  <compiler.source-path path-element="${basedir}/src" />
  <doc-sources path-element="${basedir}/src" />
</asdoc>
<!-- update swc with asdoc xml -->
<zip destfile="${deploy.dir}/${ant.project.name}.swc" update="true">
  <zipfileset dir="${temp.dir}/tempdita" prefix="docs">
    <include name="*.*"/>
    <exclude name="ASDoc_Config.xml" />
    <exclude name="overviews.xml" />
  </zipfileset>
</zip>
```

Comment: it embeds, the file size get bigger. But do not worked. I cant see the doc in my IDE, and parameters name are still weird. :( **EDIT** nvm, I made something wrong. Now I have doc working, only the params names are weird now.

Comment: I've tested this example (from starling) on flex sdk 4.6 and have both correct method description and parameters names. Try it instead of your variant, may be using _lenient_ attribute will help.

Comment: I made exactly as in that example and its working now, thanks.

Comment: can this be done without ANT I wonder? use directly command line for example?